# С кулак или в кулак?

Tags: фразеология

Можно сказать: борода должна быть длиной больше, чем в кулак?

Или правильно - с кулак?

И нужна ли запятая?

Afghan men's beards had to be long enough to exceed a fist clasped at the chin.

Comment: А Вы слышали или читали вообще где-нибудь такой сравнительный агрегат — борода-кулак?! Или, например, борода с пивной котёл? Или усов косая сажень?! Борода бывает лопатой, клинышком... ну, ещё как-то. А кулаком... не слыхивал. С кулак — это к вещам объёмным, к картошке, например.

Comment: Для перевода этого текста лучше перевести "кулак" как "4 пальца".

Comment: Да, то, что это перевод, и то,  что это афганская борода, существенно. В русском такой образности у "кулака" нет. Марк Из в этом прав.  Хотя "4 пальца" - тоже не идеально.

Answer (score 3):

Выражения "с кулак" и "в кулак" в значении "такого-то размера" - оба несут оттенок разговорности, с налетом архаизма.

Здесь "в кулак", видимо, не подходит. Выражение "[размером] во что-то" не предполагает дополнительного указания отношения (больше, меньше, не больше), 
так что я этот вариант отвожу.

***"Больше/более чем с кулак"*** - думаю, вполне годится как разговорная форма. Ну и "не более, чем в кулак" и т.д. Иногда встречается рекомендация писать "более чем" без запятой,  поскольку здесь нет сравнения как такового, но это отдельный разговор...

(+) 04.05.2015.

> Afghan men's beards had to be long enough to exceed a fist clasped at the chin.

Тут, думаю, лучше не экономить на словах и переводить близко к подстрочнику.
***Борода афганского мужчины должна быть достаточно длинной, чтобы её [едва] вмещал кулак, сжатый на подбородке***. Детали обсуждаемы.

Answer (score 2):

Больше чем (что?) кулак. При такой конструкции фразы никакие предлоги не нужны.

Если предлоги добавлять, то конструкция должна быть примерно такой: *борода по длине должна быть* **не менее чем с кулак**.

Comment: что "более(,) чем с кулак", "не менее(,) чем с кулак" - разницы грамматической никакой. И то и другое несет оттенок разговорности, но не более. Тут скорее можно о запятой спорить.